# Trigger Aws Lambda when a folder is uploaded on s3 console

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How can we trigger aws lambda only when the folder is uploaded having prefix configurations set as another folder.

for eg. we have images/ folder inside bucket. And now we want to trigger when a date folder i.e. 20181128 is uploaded to images folder, having images inside in it.

individual images shouldn't trigger lambda, rather only uploaded folder should trigger.

What s3 trigger configuration should be set in this condition?

I have gone through lot of scenarios and individual images is triggering lambda, which I don't want.
I want it should trigger only when a folder is uploaded.

Comment: Do you want it to fire an event only when the whole folder has been copied? If so, I don't think you can do this because you will get an event when the folder is created and then when a file is copied into it. Most likely the best you can do is fire on ObjectCreated events and then filter out the ones you don't want in code.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  S3 does not consider the objects to actually be "inside" a folder.

Review [How do I Use Folders in an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html) for clarification on S3's folder logic.

Answer (score 2):

How I solved this issue: with Suffixes you can define "/" as desired pattern. So if you upload for example "haha/" folder, Lambda should be triggered. Just tested that and it works.

Comment: I'm wondering how did you upload "haha/". Mind showing us?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to enable Object creation classification.

*Multipart upload completed*

**s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload**

Hope it helping you!